# Revert a function to get a specific value

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I have this function which returns `x` and `y` position an just adding up degrees, it make objects to move around in circular movements like a satellite around a planet.
In my case it moves like an ellipse because I added `+30` to dist.

```
-(CGPoint)circularMovement:(float)degrees moonDistance:(CGFloat)dist
{
  if(degrees >=360)degrees = 0;

  float x = _moon.position.x + (dist+30 + _moon.size.height/2) *cos(degrees);
  float y = _moon.position.y + (dist + _moon.size.height/2) *sin(degrees);

  CGPoint position= CGPointMake(x, y);
  return position;  
}
```

What I would like is to reverse this function, giving the `x` and `y` position of an object and getting back the dist value.

Is this possible?
If so, how would I go about achieving it?

Comment: In other words, do my trig homework for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an origin and a target, the origin having the coordinates (x1, y1) and the target has the coordinates (x2, y2) the distance between them is found using the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

The distance between the points is the square root of the difference between x2 and x1 plus the difference between y2 and y1.

In most languages this would look something like this:

x = x2 - x1;
y = y2 - y1;

distance = Math.SquareRoot(x * x + y * y);

Where Math is your language's math library.

Answer (score 1):

```
    float x = _moon.position.x + (dist+30 + _moon.size.height/2) *cos(degrees);
    float y = _moon.position.y + (dist + _moon.size.height/2) *sin(degrees);
```

is the way you have originally calculated the values, so the inverse formula would be:

dist = ((y - _moon.position.y) / (sin(degrees))) - _moon.size.height/2

You could calculate it based on x as well, but there is no point, it is simpler based on y.